# Is there any way to avoid thread pool from crashing when one thread gets exception?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

This question for .NET framework. Putting a try/catch block in the call method is a solution for this problem but I want to handle it in upper level. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Use Tasks. They run on top of the Pool and do handle/convey exceptions.

Comment: Use a BackgroundWorker object and handle [DoWork](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx).

Comment: @JohnWu - Use a BackgroundWorker object and handle _Completed_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle in upper level, but you still need to put try catch inside the call. However, instead of handling the exception inside the catch - you would add the exception into a `ConcurrentQueue` and then outside the call you can throw an `AggregateException` with the `List<Exception>` that has been queued throughout the execution of your multithreaded code.

Here is an example for how it is implemented when using `Parallel.ForEach` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-parallel-loops

Comment: Thanks, it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

No. Don't let exceptions hit the top of stacks, basically. Ever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [asynchronous delegate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/22t547yb(VS.71).aspx). Any exception not caught in the worker thread will be thrown in the main thread when you call `EndInvoke()`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void DoParallelStuff(string caller)
    {
        for (var i = 1; i<5; i++)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("I'm doing stuff for {0} on thread {1}....{2}", caller, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, i); 
            Thread.Sleep(100); 
        }
    }

    public static void Background()
    {
        DoParallelStuff("Background");
        Console.WriteLine("Background will now throw an exception.");
        var a = ((string)null).ToString();
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            Action background = Background;
            var result = background.BeginInvoke(null, null);
            DoParallelStuff("Foreground");
            background.EndInvoke(result);
        }
        catch(System.Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This was caught in the main thread: '{0}'", exception.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
I'm doing stuff for Foreground on thread 238....1
I'm doing stuff for Background on thread 459....1
I'm doing stuff for Background on thread 459....2
I'm doing stuff for Foreground on thread 238....2
I'm doing stuff for Foreground on thread 238....3
I'm doing stuff for Background on thread 459....3
I'm doing stuff for Background on thread 459....4
I'm doing stuff for Foreground on thread 238....4
Background will now throw an exception.
This was caught in the main thread: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

[Try it on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/omGSAq)